# how i can get xml data from url using php?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xml-parsing

i want to get data from remotely `XML URL` with less memory, i'm using `simplexml_load_string()` but i'm not sure about my code and the `xml feed` contain around `980 records` so what is the best way to get this big data and transform to `array`.

my code :

```
$xmlURL = 'http://www.ironitekstil.com/store/xmlfeed/productsxml.aspx?xslt=picksel.xsl';
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $xmlURL);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

if ($contents) {
  $xmlString = $contents;
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($xml);
  //echo count($xml); // 980 records
  echo '</pre>';
}else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML will load the whole data into memory (It is a DOM abstraction layer). Try XMLReader. It can open URLs an read the XML tag by tag. The current node (and its descendants can be expanded into DOM. This allows you to iterate the outer nodes (list) and load the inner part (record).

You can use the PHP Streamwrappers to open the URL directly or use CURL to fetch and store it into a local file.